# How to hide <div> box when someone clicks outside of box

Tags: jquery

How can I hide a `<div>` box when some one clicks outside of the box. I can't find the problem. So please, help me solve this problem.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test jQuery</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#button-upload').click(function() {
            $('#id_menu_profile').show();
            });
        });
        var $box = $('#id_menu_profile');
        $(document.body).click(function(){
            if (!$box.has(this).length) { // if the click was not within $box
                $box.hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <dl>
        <dt><a id="button-upload" href="#">Profile<img src="menu.png" name="arrow_profile"></a></dt>
        <!-- Submenu -->
        <div  id="id_menu_profile" style=" display: none;">
            <dt><a href="index.html">Your Id</a></dt>
            <dt><a href="index.html">Account Setting</a></dt>
            <dt><a href="index.html">Change Password</a></dt>
        </div>
    </dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's `$('#id_menu_profile').show();` doing? Isn't it supposed to show the div?

Comment: $ is just a normal variable. You can do var $ = 42 in javascript/jquery.

Comment: @Nelson, $box is a perfectly valid javascript variable name.

Comment: @dherman and Sebass:  Ok, one new thing I learned today!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var openDiv;

function toggleDiv(divID) {
    $("#" + divID).fadeToggle(200, function() {
        openDiv = $(this).is(':visible') ? divID : null;
    });
}

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#'+openDiv).length) {
        toggleDiv(openDiv);
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CHP5w/161/

Comment: Thanks Sebass van Boxel and all others

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `stopPropagation()` on the box click, so the event does not get to `Document` click handler, like this:

```
var $box = $('#id_menu_profile');
$(document.body).click(function(){
    // click outside $box
        $box.hide();
});

$box.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); //Don't let the box click bubble up to Document
    // click within $box
});
```